# How can a derived wxPanel's controls accessing data in it's containing wxDialog?

Tags: c++, boost, wxwidgets

I am using wxWidgets 3.1.3 and Boost 1.73.

Working on a custom preferences dialog for a modular application, here is the relevant parts of the header:

```
class PreferencesWindow : public wxDialog {
public:
    PreferencesWindow(...);  // Constructor

protected:
    wxButton* DialogButtonsApply;
    wxButton* DialogButtonsCancel;
    wxButton* DialogButtonsOK;
    wxTreebook* TreeBook;

private:
    enum {
        // Enumerated Window Ids
    };

    // Event Handlers
    virtual void OnTreeSelection(wxTreeEvent& event);
    virtual void OnApplyButton(wxCommandEvent& event);
    virtual void OnCancelButton(wxCommandEvent& event);
    virtual void OnOkayButton(wxCommandEvent& event);

    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();

    pt::ptree newPrefs;
public:
    const pt::ptree &getNewPrefs() const;
    void setNewPrefs(const pt::ptree &newPrefs);
};
```

The `pt::ptree` objects are typedefs of `boost::property_tree`s. There is a global `ptree` in `MyApp` accessible throughout the entire application. During construction, the dialog dynamically loads each module's preferences page. Each page is a derived `wxPanel`. The `newPrefs` contain the modified preferences. I need the panels to be able to access and update `newPrefs` so that when the user exits the dialog, the dialog can be responsible for updating the main preferences data — and consequently, the preferences file/registry on disk.

How do I do this?

---

## Update #1

To clarify:

During construction of `PreferencesWindow`, each of the controls are created and placed in their sizers. `Panel`, derived from `wxPanel` is then created and added to the dialog in `TreeBook->AddPage(panelName, "Panel Caption");`

Normally, the dialog will be called as a ShowModal from the main application window. However, right now, while I am creating the foundation for the PreferencesWindow, the main window is currently bypassed. The `MyApp::OnInit()` creates, and shows, the dialog, directly.

I will be making the Preferences dialog responsible for writing the options to disk, not just the main preferences variable.

Comment: can you show some more actual code? How do you instantiate that dialog and what is inside the constructor? If you are asking how to implement it - the basic idea is: you have a global wxApp pointer. In the dialog constructor you load the data from that global pointer pt::ptree data. Then you call `dlg.ShowModal()` which returns either `wxID_OK` for accepting data or `wxID_CANCEL` for rejecting them. So when you get the `wxID_OK` you call the public accessor function which retiurn the object of pt::ptree and assign it the object inside wxApp.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly is the problem, i.e. what precisely doesn't work for you, but you may find [TransferDataFromWindow()](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.3/classwx_window.html#ab8e51f36e7d8790b361c8d8c6f37b1ad) useful: this method is called when the dialog is accepted and you typically override it to copy the data from the UI into your internal data structures.

Note that you should *not* define any handlers for the standard `wxID_OK` and `wxID_APPLY` buttons, as the default behaviour should be just fine (and, as an aside, if you do define these handlers, it doesn't make much sense to make them virtual).